# Javascript div distance: show ads

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress, html, distance

For my wordpress site I want to calculate the distance between the start div and the end div of my right column (posts/pages, I could add a new div to the pages). Then, I want to calculate the distance between the start and end div of my left column (widgetcolumn). Distance right - distance left = Place left in pixels.

Then I check with PHP: if Place left > X -> Show ad.

Could anybody help me with the javascript please? I couldn't find anything about it on Google (I guess wrong keywords). I could write the php by myself.

Btw, sorry for my English.

Comment: You know that php runs on the server and javacsript in the browser? At the time that javascript is running, the php part has already been executed and sent to the browser

Answer (score 0):

You can use `offset` method from jQuery (ensure you include jquery library)

For example

```
var y_top = left_top_div.offset().y;
var y_bottom = left_bottom_div.offset().y;
var distance_right = y_bottom - y_top;
```

You can select left_top_div by either giving those div's ID's or if they are dynamic (and you can't ID them), then you could do the following

```
var left_top_div = left_container.find('div:first-child');
var left_bottom_div = left_container.find('div:last-child');
```

left_container will be your right column HTML element

Comment: as @Ikke has mentioned, javascript runs on your DOM in the browser, PHP runs on the server. From what I'm reading, the easiest option is to run your PHP code to present the ad, then in javascript either hide or show the ad.

As for mixing javascript and PHP, I suggest you do some learning on web development with PHP. .php pages are converted into HTML so adding javascript is not any different than adding javascript to a HTML page (typically within <script type='text/javascript'>...js code here...</script> anywhere in your HTML document)

Answer (score 0):

And if you're not using jQuery, you can use `element.offsetWidth` and `window.innerWidth` and base your calculations off of those.

```
var rightColumn, widgetColumn, totalWidth;

totalWidth = window.innerWidth;
rightColumn = document.getElementById('rightColumn').offsetWidth;
widgetColumn = document.getElementById('widgetColumn').offsetWidth;
```

And then do the math